# Connect to Cloudant Client Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cloudant

I'm trying to connect to a Cloudant client, and I've taken an example of code that I've found on [GitHub](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant).

```
public ClientBuilder getCloudantClient(String username, String password) {
    ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.account(username).
            username(username).password(password);
    return clientBuilder;
}
```

Ideally, once that method returns, I try to build and return the database by doing:

```
CloudantClient client = (CloudantClient) cloudantRestClient.getCloudantClient(USERNAME, PASSWORD).build();
Database database = client.database(DATABASE, true);
```

But for some reason, I'm getting a compile error:

> The method account(String) is undefined for the type ClientBuilder

My pom.xml dependencies for Cloudant and JUnit tests is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
      <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Is this the correct way to go with this?

Comment: Which ClientBuilder get imported into your code? Double check it's indeed `com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder`

Comment: Indeed that solved it! I had imported the javax version: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported wrong ClientBuilder, check it's indeed `com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder`